# How can I find a file in a subdirectory in Python?

Tags: python

e.g. a function should return:

- stackpath = "config/openvpn/openvpn02.json"

for stackname = "openvpn02".

How would I search "openvpn02.json" in the config directory?

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
import os

to_search = "filename"

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("."):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if "".join(f.split(".")[:-1])==to_search]:
        print os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
```